# Do all children have to be from support library if the parent is from support library

Tags: android, android-layout

If I have a android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout layout in my xml, then should all the widgets such as buttons sitting inside the layout be from the support library as well?

I mean should it be AppCompatButton or can I just use Button?

Thank you

Comment: No. It can be any widget. There is not restriction.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Put it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though `ConstraintLayout` belong in the support library, it is still a `ViewGroup`. It extends `android.view.ViewGroup`.

This means that any class/widget that extends `View` (android.view.View) can be used inside this layout.